# mv: cannot stat ‘2001010000\r’: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, shell, pipe

I have a file abc.out and I need to read it and export the content to the named pipe. My shell script as below:

```
#!/bin/ksh -x

cd /home/robert/

if [[ -s abc.out ]]; then
  sleep 2
  for i in `cat abc.out`
  do
    mv -f $i ./abc_archive/x$i
    print `pwd`/abc_archive/x$i > /home/robert/pipe_abc
    sleep 1
  done
fi
```

The content of abc.out file as below:

```
2001010000
2001010001
2001010002
```

But when I run the script with the command `sh abc.spt`, error prompted as below:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘2001010000\r’: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix this issue, many thanks!

Comment: Remove the interfering `\r` symbols ie `CR` from the input file.

Comment: Your file `abc.out` has dos line endings. You should __not__ read lines with `for i in cat`, there's  [how to read a file line by line in bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) but the same applies to ksh.

Comment: I have modified the script as below:

if [[ -s bcfin.out ]]; then
  sleep 2
  while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    mv -f $line ./bcf_archive/x$line
    print `pwd`/bcf_archive/x$line > /home/cdr/robert/test_awsget_oracle/pipe_dvf
    sleep 1
  done < bcfin.out
fi

but same error occur...

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to pipe output through either sed or tr, to remove carriage returns:
`sed -e 's/[\r\n]//g'`
or
`tr -d '\r'` if you only want to remove \r